# Civiengage pieces not showing despite being activated- Drupal, CiviCRM 4.7.15

Tags: civicampaign

Can't see custom data forms, can't make surveys or phone banks or walk lists etc.

Civicampaign is set up and configured.

Civiengage module is activated.

[image: Civiengage custom data sets[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Optce.jpg)

Comment: Welcome ... help us to help you by providing more information.  Which version of Civi are you using?  Which CMS?

Comment: Drupal, and using the latest version of CiviCRM, CiviCRM 4.7.15

Comment: have you checked Drupal Permissions?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion  Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal permission was checked, but additional Drupal **configuration** was not. This is not clear in the manual.

Thank you both for your attention!

S.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question.  It would be helpful to others if you could provide a bit more detail about what you did to solve this.